# How can I check if div is empty?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game. The following code adds either X or O to a box, however, I want to add a condition that states to only change it to X or O if its empty.

The " && (id.innerHTML="") "  is the part of the code that breaks the code. When I add this, nothing happens on click. I tried using the .getElementById as well with no luck.

```
function changeText(id) { 
  if ((turnTrueFalse()===true)&& (id.innerHTML="")){
    id.innerHTML = "X";
    document.getElementById("parag").innerHTML ="Player Two's Turn!";
    addClick();
    setTimeout(winnerAlert, 100);
  }else if ((turnTrueFalse()===false) && (id.innerHTML="")){
    id.innerHTML = "O";
    document.getElementById("parag").innerHTML ="Player One's Turn!"; 
    addClick();
    setTimeout(winnerAlert, 100);
  }
};
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: What does the parameter id represent? The id of the element or the element itself? If it is just the id, you need to use ```document.getElementById(id);```

Comment: Your code is mostly right but you have `=` instead of `===` in the .innerHTML check. That aside it's a good idea to store the state of the game elsewhere (not in the DOM) and only update the DOM according to that - separating the concern of where there's already an X or O from the presentation layer.

Comment: @tomerpacific actually for compatibility reasons (read - we're all paying for IE's mistakes) all IDs are available as global variables from JavaScript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this since typos are offtopic here and other than that your code was already correct. Thanks for the question :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `id.innerHTML` to check if a div is empty.

The sample you provided is using the assign operator `=` instead of a comparison operator `==` or `===`.

From the docs:

> Equality (==) The equality operator converts the operands if they are not of the same type, then applies strict comparison. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

Here a useful link to an [article on comparison operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) from W3Schools.

Answer (score 2):

You have = instead of === in the .innerHTML check. Be careful! :D

Answer (score 0):

u have to use === to check content and value type not only == that check for value tpye

## NOTE

=== mean equality without type coercion

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `===` (equality operator / strict comparison operator) not `=` (assignment operator):

```
} else if ((turnTrueFalse() === false) && (id.innerHTML === "")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
  <script>
        function checkEmpty(obj) {
            if(obj.innerHTML === "") {
                alert("empty");
            } 
        }
    </script>

    <div style="background: red; padding: 20px" onclick="checkEmpty(this)">not empty div</div>
    <div style="background: red; padding: 20px" onclick="checkEmpty(this)"></div>
```

Basically add "onclick" in yours div, and call a function that check if is empty or not.
But you can try your own function, just checking `obj.innerHTML === ""`